# SAP ASE and/or HANA with Microsoft .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, hana, ase

We've got a small project that we would like to be web-based. Most of our applications are SAP ASE but this project will not directly interconnect with anything existing. Therefore we can look at pretty much anything. The developers would like to use Microsoft .Net Core. I need to find out how that could be connected to ASE. We are also considering HANA as a future so we would like to know how .Net Core plays with that.

I can't seem to find driver versions from SAP's websites.
Thanks for any input you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA comes with a ADO.NET client as documented [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.04/en-US/469dee9e6d611014af70d4e9a9cd6b0a.html) and [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.04/en-US/60c13cd630c044f4a4d71b550c354a5d.html).

There are also tutorials available:
  - [Tutorials (SAP HANA Data Provider for Microsoft ADO.NET)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.04/en-US/469e00db6d611014a66fabe7c7ba2b6d.html)
  - [SAP HANA Data Provider for Microsoft .NET Sample Projects](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SAPHANA/SAP+HANA+Data+Provider+for+Microsoft+.NET+Sample+Projects)

The SAP HANA client software is part of the SAP HANA server installation and can also be downloaded separately from  https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools